# I have added avatar column to the generated users table, how to make default value to the avatar column

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Framework, I have generated all Register and Login through "$php artisan make:auth" command, now I have added a new column called "avatar" in the `users` table, and I want to set it to "noimage.jpg", so each time I register by default "noimage.jpg" will be added.

RegisterController

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'avatar' => 'noimage.jpg' //How it suppose to be?
    ]);
}
```

[image: graphical representation of users table]

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? It should work.

Comment: @Thomas its not adding noimage.jpg to the avatar column, its empty by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add `avatar` to the `$fillable` property of your model. Otherwise you cannot assign it with `create`. See docs on [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#default-attribute-values#mass-assignment).

Instead you could manually assign the avatar:

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->avatar = 'noimage.jpg';

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set a **default value** for your model is to use **Laravel lifecycle**:

```php
const DEFAULT_AVATAR = 'noimage.jpg'

protected static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();
  static::creating(function (User $user) {
      if (!$user->avatar) {
        $user->avatar = self::DEFAULT_AVATAR;
      }
  });
}
```

**See:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events